# React Native app runs on emulator, not on device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The app runs perfectly on an emulator from Android Studio, but returns

`error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment`

When I run it from the CLI

I've tried rerunning the command and creating a new project

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below in order to solve the issue:

1. Go to the root project folder.
2. Find the Android project (which the Android Studio would recognize)
3. Open it on Android Studio and fix all the Gradle-related issues.
4. Once there is no more issue, close Android Studio and rerun the
   react command.

Comment: I did that. It still won't run. After it installs on the device with the emulator, an error pops-up: `Unable to load script. Make sure you're running a metro server...`